# iOS phone crashing when manipulating navigationController's viewControllers array manually

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

This is got to be a bug with apple, but I am hoping someone has a solution for this. I am not getting a typical app crash, I am getting a phone restart (black screen of death with apple logo and everything). It seems to be related to the navigation.

In my appDelegate I conditionally push a loginController onto the app on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let nav = appdelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let loginLobby = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginLobby")

if notLoggedIn {
    nav.pushViewController(loginLobby, animated: false)
}
```

Then I have a push segue set up in the storyboard, which works fine:

[image]

However, when I hit the back button from the `signUpViewController` to go back to the `loginLobby` then the phone restarts.

I've also had this bug in several other scenario's most often when trying to release a pop a viewController after I manipulated the navigationStack in some way other than standard storyboard segue's. Anyone else have this problem?

edit: in this particular instance I don't get any error messages besides:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15
```

In other manifestations of the bug, I have gotten messages such as `Terminating since there is no system app.` and occasionally, `XPC Connection Interrupted`, not much to go off of. I have exception breakpoints enabled and they aren't catching anything.

edit: There seems to be a lot of question around what the rootView is. Here is another screenshot of the UINavigationController that I have set as the root:

[image: navigationController is the rootview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lied in the storyboard. I created a new project and laid out the views and everything seemed to be working fine. I found these couple lines in the storyboard source which weren't common between the working version and the broken version:

```
<navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="wjx-jP-5kJ"/>
<keyCommands>
    <keyCommand/>
</keyCommands>
```

I have no idea what those lines are supposed to do, or how they crept into my storyboard file, but they were what was crashing the app so hard that the phone had to restart. I removed those lines from my main project and everything worked again.

Comment: Thanks for filing radar://23743692. These lines creep in if you add a key command (Attributes inspector for UIViewController) and leave the title empty. It's a bug in IB that this XML gets written and there is no warning that it's misconfigured (radar://23193389), and a bug in UIKit that it causes a crash leading to a device restart (radar://22874926).

Answer (score 0):

You should [setViewControllers:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:) instead of pushing. If that doesn't work, you'll need to manipulate the view controller stack after the first view controller has been loaded.

Comment: Crashes just the same... The only way I can come up with to be sure the first view controller is loaded is to push it on in the homeView's viewDidLoad method, but now that I try it, that crashes also.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot add comments as I don't have enough reputation.

Are you checking if `loginLobby` is `nil`?

Perhaps wrap it in an `if let`.

```
if notLoggedIn {
    if let loginLobby = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginLobby") {
        nav.pushViewController(loginLobby, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it's nil, the loginLobby will push on just fine, the problem is when I push another viewController onto the loginLobby and then try to pop back.

Comment: Ah, got it. I believe Apple wants us to delegate one view controller as the root presenter and push all other view controllers from there. Is loginLobby a UINavigationViewController? If not, try presenting the 2nd view controller from the UINavigationController variable 'nav'.

Comment: what is the instantiateViewController of the main storyboard

Comment: the rootViewController is a UINavigationController. The loginLobby is a subclass of UIViewController (see screen shot)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not setting the root view controller? In my practice when I conditionally set the window in app delegate, this is what I do:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loginVc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController!

if (/*something meets your criteria*/) {
    self.window?.rootViewController = loginVc
}

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: The root view controller is already set in the storyboard. It's the main navigationController.